# Regular expression for matching Titles (ex: Book title)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using `jquery.validate.js` plugin to validate a form and I want regex with match Titles(Books or Non-Books or any Title of products)  but I failed to match and I wanted a regex which match following,

=> From 'A-Z' , 'a-z', whitespace, as well as tab space , special characters like '  (  ' , '  )  ' , - ,  _  ,  and 'coma' , dot , semicolon, ifen ,' : ', and all numbers

I used following regex for above:

1. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'\-_\s]$/`
2. `/^[\d,\w,\s\;\:\()]$/`
3. `/^[^.-_#][A-Za-z0-9_ -.]+$/` - this is showing error when Title starts from upper case 'A'

and I referred following sites

http://regexpal.com/  // in this site i checked the above characters bot it showed error on validate

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't shown a example how your title looks like.

Comment: you can try with this ====> " Wings of fire", : by '(A.P.J)' 2 copies ;.

Comment: @RajeshHatwar Easy, `/.*/`.

Comment: @RajeshHatwar You'll have to provide more test cases, including what to reject, and explain why one is accepted and one is rejected, and also show us what you've tried so far and tell us what it does wrong.

Comment: Also, why did you tag your question with [tag:java] and [tag:nsregularexpression] when you're using Javascript?

Comment: 'Encyclopædia Britannica' is not a valid book title?

Comment: at least it should match exactly like this title ===>  " Wings of fire", : by '(A.P.J)' 2 copies ;.   <===== till hear and in this title i added all characters what i wanted even special characters (except a-z and A-Z and 0-9)

Comment: sorry for that i was using in some other project if i get good solution i can use in future

Comment: Well, it's still tag spamming. More annoyingly so in here since all three platforms will have subtly different regexp syntaxes. Pick the one that's applicable right now.

Answer (score 4):

This regex should match what you want `/^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-_,\.;:()]+$/`.
Special characters like . & - need escaping with a backslash. You also need a + or * at the end of the square braces to say 'one or more' or 'any number of' respectively.

Comment: yes i finaly got this, you just have to add like this => ^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-_,\.:;()]+$

Comment: sorry this one ==> ^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-_,\.:;()''""]+$

Answer (score 0):

I think this one you want [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/8bGmM8EWn6)

```
^\w++(?:[.,_:()\s-](?![.\s-])|\w++)*$
```

Description

```
^           # Start of string
\w++        # Match one or more alnum characters, possessively
(?:         # Match either
 [.,_:()\s-]  # a  "special" character
 (?![.\s-]) #  aserting that it's really single
|           # or
 \w++       # one or more alnum characters, possessively
)*          # zero or more times
$           # End of string
```

Comment: but it's not matching '(' and ')'

Comment: @RajeshHatwar escape those characters.. something like this `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: whatever special character you want just add it in part  [.,_:()\s-]

Comment: pleas can you see my comments above

Comment: ya i got it see ===> ^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-_,\.:;()''""]+$